# Getting "See also" section in a Wikipedia page

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I want to get all the links in the "See also" section in a wikipedia article, but wikipedia API for python ([Wikipedia documentation](http://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)) doesn't provide those information. Even if I use "page" function to get the whole content of a page to extract the "See also" section, that section is usually empty! (while if you take a look at that webpage with your browser, it won't be empty!).

[image: Nothing is appeared in "See also" section!]

[image: The "See also" section is not empty!]
So, I think, the only way for extracting those information is to parse the HTML page. Any suggestion that help me to extract those information without parsing the HTML page is appreciated.

Comment: It's ridiculous!!! without receiving even a line of comment, two person just gave me negative points!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a reasonable question to me. Anyway, you may still have to parse HTML, but the RESTBase API provides a 'mobile-sections' endpoint that groups the output HTML by section heading. The API endpoint looks like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/mobile-sections/Facebook

[Documentation provided here](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#!/Mobile/get_page_mobile_sections_title_revision)

The API response contains an object with the 'sections' property like this

```
"remaining": {
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": 39,
        "text": ...,
        "toclevel": 1,
        "line": "See also",
        "anchor": "See_also"
      },
    ...
    ]
}
```

With that response, you can select the HTML from the section whose `line` property matches the string "See also".